# how to set colorscale with reference to dates in plotly python

Tags: python, date, colors, plotly

first question so go easy on me please!
I'm trying to create a scatter plot in plotly where the points are coloured according to a datetime column, but it seems to error out. it works fine if I set the color to, say, a numeric column. is there a way to do this please?

Sample code below. if I change color to, say `np.arange(0,graph_data.shape[0])` it would work fine but the colorbar labels would be meaningless.

```
    fig1 = go.Figure()

    fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                        x=graph_data['x_data'],
                        y=graph_data['y_data'],
                        mode='markers',
                        marker={
                            'size': 15,
                            'opacity': 0.95,
                            'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'},
                            'color': graph_data['date'],
                            'colorbar': {'title': 'Date'},
                            'colorscale': 'Viridis'
                            }
                        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but one possible workaround is to convert your `datetime` to seconds after a given date. You could try the following using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
```

This will then be an integer which will be understood by the scatter function.

Comment: thanks, this got me partway there but I still had an issue with the labels on the colorbar not being the dates the colours actually represented. But you can customise your colorbar labels by setting 'ticktext' in the colorbar dictionary. in my case days rather than seconds sufficed, and I wanted to show the date every 7 days so used a slightly different function, and some very un-pythonic code to get there - i'll add my answer code

Answer (score 2):

Using the principles of Matt's work around, I created a 'number of days from start' column for the colorscale to reference and then customised tick labels and spacing on the colour bar as follows:

```
    # 'date' column contains the dates I want to set colorscale on
    # set minimum date
    min_date = graph_data['date'].min()

    # create column giving number of days from the minimum date, as the colour reference
    graph_data['days'] = graph_data['date'].apply(lambda x: (x-min_date).days)

    # here I want colorbar tick labels every 7 days, so I create a list of the
    # required multiples of 7 
    max_days = graph_data['days'].max()
    fig1ticks = np.arange(0, (int(max_days/7)+1)*7, 7)

    # use datetime.timedelta function to create the dates that match the tick values
    fig1datetimes = [min_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in fig1ticks.tolist()]

    # and create text strings of these dates in a suitable format
    fig1text = [i.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") for i in fig1datetimes]

    fig1 = go.Figure()

    fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                        x=graph_data['x_data'],
                        y=graph_data['y_data'],
                        mode='markers',
                        marker={
                            'size': 15,
                            'opacity': 0.95,
                            'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'},

                            # set color reference to new 'days' column
                            'color': graph_data['days'],

                            # set 'tickvals' and 'ticktext' in colorbar dict
                            'colorbar': {'title': 'Date',
                                         'tickvals': fig1ticks,
                                         'ticktext': fig1text,
                                         },
                            'colorscale': 'Viridis'
                            }
                        )
    )
```